# Click not working correctly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to make a List-Group with custom content. The problem is that the list item must have a property called "active" so the background of the element is blue. What I want is that when I click on another list item, it must gain the "active" class so it can have a blue background.

here is some code:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 list-group lista"><!--Center of the container-->
            <a href="" class="list-group-item active" id="act">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Actualizacion</h4>
                <p class="list-group-item-text">Realizamos actualizacion de software ya sea que tu telefono este lento, presente errores extranos
                    en su comportamiento o simplemente quieras subir la version actual.
                </p>
            </a>

            <a href="" class="list-group-item" id="unl">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Liberacion</h4>
                <p class="list-group-item-text">
                    Quieres cambiar de operador y no puedes porque tu telefono no tiene las bandas abiertas?
                    Vas a salir de viaje y necesitar una SIM CARD en el exterior?
                    Trae tu telefono podemos realizarle un desbloqueo de bandas para que trabaje con cualquier operador
                    a nivel mundial (1).
                </p>
            </a>
        </div>
```

and here is my script:

```
$(".lista").on("click", "a", function(){

$(this).siblings().removeClass("active");

$(this).addClass("active");});
```

When I try this out the the item I clicked gains the blue background but loses it immediately and the previous still keeps the blue background.
How to fix this please .

Comment: It's working fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/9mojfc8z/

Comment: [It's working fine](http://jsfiddle.net/kqv58763/). What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: thanks @Terry I just copied the script you put in jsfiddie and now is working fine thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Your code is work fine, and gained the blue background. But, you have anchor tag which is make redirect. Put this, `e.preventDefault();`.

```
 $(".lista").on("click", "a", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine but you can try the below one.

Remove active class from all the  element and add the active class to the element which is clicked

```
$(".lista").on("click", "a", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
     $('a.list-group-item').removeClass("active");
     $(this).addClass("active");
});
```